Connecting to the mActionDigitizeWithCurve map tool toggled signal with PyQGIS
Using PyQGIS for QGIS 3.34 and 3.38, I want to connect the toggled signal of the mActionDigitizeWithCurve map tool (in the Digitizing toolbar) to a function for such function to be executed when the tool is active.
Using QGIS 3.16 mActionDigitizeWithCurve was part of the Advanced Digitizing toolbar and it was the first action of iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().actions():
print([ action.objectName() for action in iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().actions() ])

['mActionDigitizeWithCurve', 'mEnableAction', 'ActionMoveFeatureTool', 'mActionRotateFeature', 'mActionSimplifyFeature', 'mActionAddRing', 'mActionAddPart', 'mActionFillRing', 'mActionDeleteRing', 'mActionDeletePart', 'mActionReshapeFeatures', 'mActionOffsetCurve', 'mActionReverseLine', 'mActionTrimExtendFeature', 'mActionSplitFeatures', 'mActionSplitParts', 'mActionMergeFeatures', 'mActionMergeFeatureAttributes', 'ActionPointSymbolTools']

Using QGIS 3.34 or 3.38, such action is part of a drop-down button (QWidgetAction) of iface.digitizeToolBar() and is not listed among the toolbar actions:
print([ action.objectName() for action in iface.digitizeToolBar().actions() ])

['mActionAllEdits', 'mActionToggleEditing', 'mActionSaveLayerEdits', '', 'mActionAddFeature', 'ActionVertexTool', 'mActionMultiEditAttributes', 'mActionDeleteSelected', 'mActionCutFeatures', 'mActionCopyFeatures', 'mActionPasteFeatures', 'mActionUndo', 'mActionRedo']

The unnamed 4th action is the drop-down button containing the mActionDigitizeWithCurve action, but I failed to find a way to retrieve the related QAction object.
How can I connect a function to the toggled signal of the mActionDigitizeWithCurve action?

It seems that the menu which contains the digitize with curve action belongs to a QToolButton child of the digitize tool bar, rather than a QAction.
The following should work:
digitize_tool_bar = iface.digitizeToolBar()
digitize_menu = [btn.menu() for btn in digitize_tool_bar.findChildren(QToolButton) if btn.menu()][0]
digitize_with_curve_action = [a for a in digitize_menu.actions() if a.objectName() == 'mActionDigitizeWithCurve'][0]
print(digitize_with_curve_action)

Prints:
<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAction object at 0x74c1e85e3370>

Or, perhaps a bit more 'future proof' in case there is more than one tool button with a menu:
digitize_tool_bar = iface.digitizeToolBar()
digitize_menus = [btn.menu() for btn in digitize_tool_bar.findChildren(QToolButton) if btn.menu()]
digitize_with_curve_action = [a for menu in digitize_menus for a in menu.actions() if a.objectName() == 'mActionDigitizeWithCurve' ][0]
print(digitize_with_curve_action)


The improved script doesn't work: "NameError: name 'menu' is not defined"

I've submitted an edit to fix the improved script in the answer.

Andrea Giudiceandrea, I voted to reject your edit. No disrespect as it would probably get the error resolved, but @BenW has corrected their own answer.

@Matt the answer was initially correct. Then the author edited the answer adding a second improved solution, which however was incorrect. Then I submitted an edit to fix it. Then my edit was rejected.
There have been no other edits by the author up to now, so the second improved solution is still incorrect.

My apologies, then I misread something.
